# How to avoid slashes when user inserts string with a quote using PHP PDO and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So in order to avoid SQL injections, I decided to start using the PHP PDO functions to connect to my MySQL database. However, is it possible to avoid having the \ put on the table when a user puts a quote in?

Here's my code:

```
$insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tests 
        (name, author, category, description, num_attempts, audience, date_uploaded, source, public) VALUES 
        (:testName, '$userId', '$category', :desc, '0', '$audience', '$date', 'Web', '0')");
        $insert->bindParam(':testName', $testName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->bindParam(':desc', $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insert->execute();
```

Note the testName, that's a user input. I don't want a \ being placed on the database whenever someone puts a quotation mark. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on, that causes the slashes to be added. Magic quotes is a broken security concept and has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3, so for future-proof code set magic quotes to off.

Comment: It seems like this would be the correct answer, but I have checked my php.ini and it has the options as Off. My server doesn't allow php modifications from .htaccess - I'm using a POST method to send the string using javascript and ajax, do they somehow insert this quote escaping?

Comment: You can go over the $_GET and $_POST arrays and apply [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to each member.